# Unable to use System.out in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new World();

        System.out.println("HelloWorld Java");
    }
}
```

Compiling with javac results in this error:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Documents\GitHub\ECS\src\Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("HelloWorld Java");
          ^
symbol:   variable out
location: class System
```

It's the most puzzling error I've ever gotten. Although I suppose it's important to note that this is my first real programming without the use of an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local class called System. Don't use standard JDK names for your own classes.